# Need Help in solving Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I am trying to solve another [Question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/binary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/the-old-monk/description/)

I have implemented the binary search function required to solve this problem but i am unable to return the correct value which would help me in solving this question.Here's my code.

Please help me in solving this question.

```
def BinarySearch(arr,low,high,search):
    while(low<=high):

        middle=(low+high)/2
        int_mid=int(middle)
        print(int_mid)

        if arr[int_mid]==search:
            return int_mid
        elif arr[int_mid]>search:
            low=int_mid+1
        elif arr[int_mid]<search:
            high=int_mid-1


    return arr[int_mid]


tc=int(input())

while(tc>0):
    size=int(input())

    A=list(map(int,input().split()))
    B=list(map(int,input().split()))

    monkiness=[]


    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):

            if (j>=i):
                y=BinarySearch(B,0,len(B),B[j])
                z=BinarySearch(A,0,len(A),A[i])

            print(y,z)
            if y>=z:

                m=j-i
                monkiness.append(m)

if len(monkiness)==0:
    print(0)
else:
    print(monkiness)
    maxiumum=max(monkiness)
    print(maxiumum)
tc-=1
```

Comment: What is your input and output?

Comment: It's around 1000+values so it wont fit here.Plus the code cannot print the output as the online compiler has a time limit and my code exceeds that time limit.The hyperlink mentions the question as well as the sample input and output.

Comment: Binary search is not the best approach, but it can probably work. But you need to create a test case yourself -- if you can't test the code except on some random website, probably there's more or different problems than the one you've guessed you've got. If you're asking other people to find the problems, providing a test-case that fails or is too slow is almost mandatory.

Comment: I am using binary search as the question specifies that I need to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need binary search here ('here' means code you provided, not problem solution)
2. Even if you required binary search, `BinarySearch` is for non-decreasing array, but you have non-increasing array.
3. The goal is to find solution, that runs in less, than N^2 time, by exploiting the fact, that arrays are sorted.

Comment: I need binary search to find the solution as if i use linear search,i get the time exceeded error.And i am using the binary search for arrays ordered by descending order.All the inputs are in descending order.